# Reactivity doesn't work using state in VueJS and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an increment field, I do everything right. Updates the states in the vue dev tols, etc... However it doesn't update the values ​​of the component's buttons there. I've tried everything already. But the reactivity is not happening in this case.

[image: Component buttons]

I'll leave a part of the VUEX code to see if it helps:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {   
    productsInBag: []
  },  
  mutations: {     
    ADD_TO_BAG(state, product) {
      state.productsInBag.push(product);
      localStorage.setItem("productsInBag", JSON.stringify(state.productsInBag))
    },
    REMOVE_FROM_BAG(state, productId) {
      let updatedBag = state.productsInBag.filter(item => productId != item.id)
      state.productsInBag = updatedBag     
    },
    DECREASE_PRODUCT(state, product) {     
      let itemIndex = state.productsInBag.findIndex(x => x.id === product.id)       
      state.productsInBag[itemIndex].quantity--   
    },
    INCREASE_PRODUCT(state, productId) {
      state.productsInBag.find(item => item.id === productId).quantity++      
    }
      
  },
  actions: {
    addToBag ({ commit }, payload) {          
      commit('ADD_TO_BAG', payload.product)
    },
    removeFromBag ({ commit }, payload) {
      if (confirm('Você quer remover este produto do carrinho ?')) {
        commit('REMOVE_FROM_BAG', payload.product.id)
      }      
    },
    decreaseProduct ({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('DECREASE_PRODUCT', payload.product)
    },
    increaseProduct ({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('INCREASE_PRODUCT', payload.product.id)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProductsInBag(state) {
        return state.productsInBag
    },   
  } 
}
```

I'll also leave a part of the component code:

```js
import globalMixin from '@/mixins/globalMixins'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'CartView',
  mixins: [globalMixin],
  computed: {
    ...mapState('products', ['productsInBag'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters("products", ["getProductsInBag"]),
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="cart container-fluid">
    <div class="cart-item-products row" v-for="product in productsInBag" :key="product.id">
      <div class="col-lg-3 cart-item-products-description">
        <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 cart-item-products-description">
        <button @click="() => $store.dispatch({type: 'products/decreaseProduct', product})">-</button>
          <span class="quantity">{{ product.quantity }}</span>
        <button @click="() => $store.dispatch({type: 'products/increaseProduct', product})">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 cart-item-products-description">
        <p>
          <span class="value-description">{{ brazilianCurrency(product.price) }}</span> à vista ou {{ divideValue(product.price) }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 cart-item-products-description">
        <p>
          <span class="value-description">{{ brazilianCurrency(product.price * product.quantity) }}</span> à vista ou {{ divideValue(product.price * product.quantity) }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In Vue Devtools states work perfectly. Look:

[image]

Would be great If you can help me. I've been looking for a solution for this for 6 hours.

Comment: The question should contain the necessary code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors ..

Comment: Use, the `set` operator to mutate data in state and reflect in the component, like this- `Vue.set(state.productsInBag, itemIndex, product)`

Comment: This serves no good purpose, `state.productsInBag[itemIndex] = product`. It would cause a problem with reactivity but here it likely does nothing, why does DECREASE_PRODUCT implementation differ from INCREASE_PRODUCT ? Otherwise I see no problem, consider providing a way to reproduce it, it needs to be debugged. It's not shown how data is added to the store

Comment: @EstusFlask In the vuex documentation it shows that mapGetters can be called in computed.

Comment: @Neha Soni, It worked that way. Thanks! Could you look at my code and tell me if it's the best way ? https://jsfiddle.net/kwx06dp2/

Comment: I posted the answers to explain them in a better way.

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger Can you clarify what you mean? It's a mistake to use mapGetters in `methods`. Check what Vuex helpers actually do. mapGetters creates an object with computeds as values, which is intended to be used in `computed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Vue. set](https://if(itemIndex%20!=%20-1)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20product.quantity--%20%20%20%20%20Vue.set(state.productsInBag,%20itemIndex,%20product)%20%20%20%7D) is a tool that allows us to add a new property to an already reactive object and makes sure that this new property is ALSO reactive.**

So, according to your problem, `Vue.set` will work well for you. Use it like this-

```
Vue.set(state.productsInBag, itemIndex, product)
```

**Optional-**

Also by looking at your fiddle's code, you can make a common function in your helper file to find the product's index like his-

```
export const findByIndex = (arr, matcher) => {
 return arr.findIndex(item => item.id === matcher)
}
```

And import this function in your js file like this-

```
import { findByIndex } from "YOUR_HELPER_FILE_PATH"
```

Now, the mutations can use like this-

```
DECREASE_PRODUCT(state, product) {     
  let itemIndex = findByIndex(state.productsInBag, product.id)
  if(itemIndex != -1) {
    product.quantity--
    Vue.set(state.productsInBag, itemIndex, product)
  }
},

INCREASE_PRODUCT(state, product) {    
  let itemIndex = findByIndex(state.productsInBag, product.id)
  if(itemIndex != -1) {
    product.quantity++
    Vue.set(state.productsInBag, itemIndex, product)
  }
}
```

**A Little Tip-**

Instead of making two mutation methods, a single mutation can be created which will accept the `product_id` and `operation` (increase or decrease) in an object, like this-

```
UPDATE_PRODUCT(state, payload) {
  // payload is an object which will have some data
  let itemIndex = findByIndex(state.productsInBag, payload.product_id)
  if(itemIndex != -1) {
    payload.operation == 'increase' ? product.quantity-- : product.quantity++;
    Vue.set(state.productsInBag, itemIndex, product)
  }
}
```